# Combinations w/ repetition (ascending order lists) solution verification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, combinations

Here is an answer given to a problem from the book I'm working out of along with my answer, and a question about the discrepancy:

Question:
How many lists of form $(w,x,y,z)$ where $w,x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}^+\cup0$ and $0\le w \le x \le y \le z \le 9$.

My answer was:

$${10 + 4 - 1 \choose 4} = {13 \choose 4}$$

The correct answer is:

$${14 \choose 4}.$$

Now, to me this was a straight forward combinations with repetition problem in which I repeatedly select from the integers $0-9$. Once I've counted the number of unique multisets I can form, I am done since there is one correct order per set (thus the variables can be designated after the fact).

What am I missing?

Comment: Your answer is correct. You are in effect putting $4$ indistinguishable balls into $10$ distinguishable boxes, and that can be done in $\binom{4+10-1}{10-1}=\binom{13}9=\binom{13}4$ ways.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott the problem is, the book gives the justification that the list can be encoded with $10$ stars and $4$ bars, where $w$ is the number of stars to the left of the first bar, $x$ the number of stars to the left of the second bar, etc. So the encoding is: $(2,3,6,9)=** \vert * \vert *** \vert *** \vert *$
$(0,3,3,7)=\vert *** \vert\vert **** \vert ***$
$(1,1,1,1)=* \vert\vert\vert\vert ********* $. So it's not just a fluke, this is how it is being taught. That is, the approach is to choose $4$ slots out of $14$ slots for the bars.

Comment: That *idea* is fine, but it’s been carried out incorrectly. There should be only $9$ stars: you never need the tenth star.